Does God or a non-physical Necessary Being have to be omni-potent?
If the Necessary Being was non-physical but not an abstract object either, does it have to be omnipotent. Also, what is the relationship between omnipotence and the modal argument?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@Hido I don't know what you mean by "Necessary Being". Could you give a non-trivial definition in your question?

it is a being which has to exist in all possible worlds, it is eternal, uncaused, independent, impossible to not exist.

@Speakpigeon Here's one : "I infer a being [existence] of all beings, with which I am even less acquainted through its transcendental concept, and of whose unconditioned necessity I can make for myself no concept at all." Kant A340/B398

The question should refer to a specific variant of the ontological argument, if that's what it's about. Answerers should not have to guess which one is meant

@Chris Degnen "Here's one: "I infer a being [existence] of all beings, with which I am even less acquainted through its transcendental concept, and of whose unconditioned necessity I can make for myself no concept at all." This was clearly not a definition, but an admission that he didn't have one.

@Speakpigeon In the link A340/B398 Kant also defines it as "the absolute synthetic unity of all conditions for the possibility of things in general". Tricky to grasp for sure.

@ChrisDegnen "the absolute synthetic unity of all conditions for the possibility of things in general" I call that "private language".

@Speakpigeon I think it's rather like if one didn't conceptualise anything, what would one have? Conceptualising conditions things. If one didn't condition anything one would have unconditioned existence which is the necessary basis for conditioning conceptualisations, i.e. thoughts. But one could not 'think' it because then it would become conditioned. Many esoteric philosophies promote non-conceptualisation in meditation.

@ChrisDegnen "Conceptualising conditions things" What does that mean to "condition things"? - 2. "one would have unconditioned existence" The existence of reality is by definition not subject to any condition. We need to have the concept of reality to understand that this is the case. - 3. "for conditioning conceptualisations, i.e. thoughts" What does that mean?

@Speakpigeon Unconditioned experience (if it can be such) is raw perception, sensation. In contrast, conditioning experience is applying judgements and discriminations, naming and conceptualising forms from the raw field of reception.

The possibility of error is introduced through conditioning and judgement.

@ChrisDegnen "Unconditioned experience (if it can be such) is raw perception, sensation (...) The possibility of error is introduced through conditioning and judgement" This judgement clearly introduced an error, for it is possible for perception as well to introduce an error.

What do you mean by non-physical but not abstract?  Do you mean like a light wave or electromagnetic energy?  The metaphysical conception of God usually is necessary, non-physical, and by definition, abstract in the sense of being beyond sensibility.  Are you asking can there be something necessary that we are incapable of sensing in any kind of way?

No, I don't think so. For example, it might be the case that God exists and that there are also plenty of other non-physical necessary beings with limited power or no power at all: e.g., angels, separated human souls, abstract entities like numbers, propositions, properties, and relations. Or, it might be the case that God doesn't exist, but there are still non-physical necessary beings: most obviously, abstract entities. Even in an atheistic universe with concrete non-physical entities (whatever those might be: maybe instantiations of phenomenal properties, souls, or ghosts) or Platonic Forms (which are arguably abstract but aren't causally inert), it would take a serious argument to show that attributing necessity to them carries a commitment to attributing omnipotence.
That being said, there are arguments in the history of philosophy that try to argue from a specific form of necessity (necessity per se or self-existence) to omnipotence. But it’s far more controversial whether there is any being with this specific form of necessity than whether there are any necessary beings more broadly speaking.

sir, my bad for forgotting to add these. I count abstract objects outside because they can not cause anything, and by definition angels and souls are not necessary being, they are dependant so with that being said, if we assume something other then God, a system, exists necessarily and it has a causation power, does it have to be omnipotent? And it has no limiting factor.

For Aquinas, anyway, angels and separated human souls are necessary beings, as are the heavens and prime matter. I'm not sure what "definition" of necessity is supposed to exclude dependence, but it's very common to make some sort of necessity per se / necessity per aliud distinction (as in the Third Way). In any case, maybe check out https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/god-necessary-being/

thank you sir. Does necessary and İndependent being needs to have mind or conscious?

That’s a matter of controversy. It would certainly take a serious argument to show that utterly mindless necessary and independent beings are impossible.

sir I think same as you. Do you know any arguments about why necessary being should have mind?

Necessity, Godness (being a very powerful agent), omnipotence (absolutist power), and "creator of everything" are logically distinct claims.  They are often coupled by theists, but each are logically distinct, so support for each of these claims is potentially an independent question.
The modal ontological argument is not highly thought of in philosophic circles, see these two sets of answers:  What's to stop you from plugging in something else like a necessary being in the Modal Ontological argument? Does this modal ontological argument prove the existence of God?  The first link also explains how  "necessary" is often misused even by philosophers, and offers critiques that it appears that "necessity" claims are not credible.
There are logic problems associated with "creator of everything" -- in part focussed on how "logic" would be among what is created, and this makes the testability of creator God claims logically suspect due to circularity.
The existence of the minimal God claim, of a powerful spiritual agent, is testable in principle, and does not seem to suffer from the problematic issues that most of these other questions suffer from.

@user:29339 sir  the second link does not say something negative about theism but it upradge the argument. The first link you have your answer there. I got a question, what is the problem about the second answer?

Necessary Being, assuming that it exists, would end up being omnipotent because if you assume the Principle of Sufficient Reason (as you have assumed, because you reject the existence of brute contingent facts), there is nothing external to itself to limit its power. Everything depends on it. So definitionally, it ends up being omnipotent, but in practice, it can only act with regards to its essence, which e.g. under Absolute Divine Simplicity would imply a type of singular emanationism where it creates only a single 'most perfect' entity.
When it comes to the Modal Ontological Argument, it tries to establish the existence of the Necessary Being. From what I wrote above, it would also follow that it is omnipotent for the same reasons as before.

Sir do you have or know articles for me to learn about this?

The principle of sufficient reason does not hold.  No justification can satisfy the Munchausen trilemma, hence nothing can satisfy the PSR.   https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64638/is-the-m%c3%bcnchhausen-trilemma-really-a-trilemma/64646#64646

Also, here are two discussions of the modal ontological argument:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/96949/whats-to-stop-you-from-plugging-in-something-else-like-a-necessary-being-in-the https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41671/does-this-modal-ontological-argument-prove-the-existence-of-god/49520#49520  None of the answers here think that it is a good argument for a God existing.

@Dcleve sir this question is not about God tho, I used it for analogy. My question is if there is a necessary being with a causation power, does it have to be omnipotent?
